# Profile details in outlook rest api

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

Starting from here: https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php

Scopes:

```
private static $scopes = array("openid"
  ,"profile"
  ,"offline_access"
  ,"https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read"
  ,"https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read"
  );
```

When I authenticate I get in id_token only some basic info about the profile.

With:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts
```

I get some very nice details about contacts, like phone numbers that I'm specially interested in my case.

**Is possible to get the same level of details for the current user profile as you get for one of its contacts when is accessed through the api?**

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Microsoft Graph API:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

The response should like as following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 491

{
  "businessPhones": [
       "businessPhones-value"
   ],
   "displayName": "displayName-value",
   "givenName": "givenName-value",
   "jobTitle": "jobTitle-value",
   "mail": "mail-value",
   "mobilePhone": "mobilePhone-value",
   "officeLocation": "officeLocation-value",
   "preferredLanguage": "preferredLanguage-value",
   "surname": "surname-value",
   "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value",
   "id": "id-value"
}
```

[Graph API - Get user](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)